# Radiation from rotating charge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

Does a charge +q rotating in a orbit of a definite radius around another charge -q radiate energy? What will the intensity of radiation emitted by such a system at a distance which is much larger than orbit radius?

Comment: We should ask whether the charges are free to move or constrained, e.g. within two conductors connected by an insulating bar.

Comment: Do the two charges have the same mass - in other words, are you asking about an oscillating dipole?

Comment: Yes. Masses are same. But I don't think that this system can be considered as oscillating dipole as neither length nor magnitude of charge is changing with time.

Comment: The projection of the charge along a line of sight will look like a dipole - but you have the positive charge accelerating in one direction while the negative charge accelerates in the opposite direction; I think that makes this a much more interesting question.

Answer (score 1):

It will radiate because the charges are subject to centripetal acceleration and the rotation rate will reduce as energy is lost (unless you drive the rotation to put energy back in).

In a non-relativistic scenario the power radiated is given by Larmor 
with $$a=v^2/r$$

(I'm assuming I don't need to define those variables, just check here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_force)
Larmor is defined here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larmor_formula)

This gives

$$P=\frac{2q^2v^4}{6\pi \epsilon _0 c^3r^2}$$

If you are observing the intensity at distance D (and simplifying the reality by assuming an even angular distribution) it is given by

$$I=\frac{q^2v^4}{4\pi^2 \epsilon _0 c^3r^2D^2}$$

Using SI units should give you a result in S.I. candela I think.

as you might expect, if D is very large the intensity will tend to zero.

Comment: Can you provide any web link or source where expression for intensity is derived systematically?

Comment: Bearing in mind I ignored the angualr distribution of the radiation to get a simple estimate. I is just P/A, (I remebered it, and the surface area of a sphere). Anyway it is on this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensity_(physics)

Comment: How does this answer change when there are two opposite charges (Q+ and Q-, per the question) orbiting each other? Does that make for a dipole (with possibly a $1\r^3$ type drop-off of radiation)?

Comment: The $1/r^3$ equations are for field strength. Well, assuming that's what you are looking at. The field strength at any point is the rate of change of potential energy - that is the differential of the equation for P above.
But it's true I have given equations for a single charge q, to get result for multiple charges sum multiple applications of the equation. to make this easier in the far field for a dipole we can neglect the differences in D, and just double it.